# How to find value in array of object in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, express

I want to get the value of a nested object within an array. I get the _id of the parent object, as well as the _id of the child object within the array, but I am not able to retrieve the value of "solvedOn" to toggle a checkbox (behavior).

So this is an example object with its nested objects:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("6292722ea8173377658171ff"),
  title: 'work-list',
  tasks: [
    {
      name: 'go to work',
      createdOn: '2022-05-28T19:04:14.799Z',
      solvedOn: false,
      _id: new ObjectId("6292722ea8173377658171f8")
    },
    {
      name: 'do some work',
      createdOn: '2022-05-30T17:20:56.272Z',
      solvedOn: false,
      _id: new ObjectId("6294fdbf8717c09237c5098e")
    }
  ],
  __v: 0
}
```

So I already went this way:

```
  List.findOne(
    {_id: listID},
    {tasks: {
      $elemMatch: {
        _id: taskID
      }
    }},
    (err, res) => {
      console.log(res.tasks);
    }
  )
```

When I try to log "res.tasks.solvedOn" then the result is 'undefined'. Even though, when I use the placeholder: "res.tasks.$.solvedOn"

This is what I get back:

```
[
  {
    name: 'go to work',
    createdOn: '2022-05-28T19:04:14.799Z',
    solvedOn: false,
    _id: new ObjectId("6292722ea8173377658171f8")
  }
]
```

So how I can work with the value of "solvedOn" to toggle the status of a checkbox?

Like:

```
If (true) { // set value to false } else {// set value to true }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write `res.tasks[0].solvedOn` instead of `res.tasks.solvedOn`

As your `tasks` is an array

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem. Now I have another issue, whenever the value is true, the value I get back is undefined. But I think there is the problem within the way I populate my ejs file.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `res.tasks`, it returns an array of tasks. So you cannot get the `solvedOn` value with `res.tasks.solvedOn`.
You should give the index of the array to get the value of it.
Like `res.tasks[0].solvedOn`.

My suggestion is first you get all the tasks in an array like:

```
const tasks = res.tasks;
```

Then map it wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If the item you need may not be the first one, you can use an aggregation pipeline with a `$filter`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {_id: ObjectId("6292722ea8173377658171ff")}
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      res: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$tasks",
          as: "item",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$item._id", ObjectId("6294fdbf8717c09237c5098e")]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uJU5RLX2fvN)

Comment: Thanks. In this situation, since I find only one objection I can work with array[0] since I only get one result. But I think I will need your way soon too 