# Nodejs | Object property is available but it's returning 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I've been trying to solve this for about 2 hours. I am returning an object in Nodejs. This object has 3 properties. I can access the first two, but when I try to access the third property, I get the 'undefined' warning. I'm about to go crazy can you help me please?

Request:

```
  const categories = await Categories.find({}); //mongoose query
  console.log(categories[0]); //its returning Object
  console.log(categories[0].category); //its returning  []
  console.log(categories[0]._id); //its returning  new ObjectId("6257233b897c3b8785ff625b")
  console.log(categories[0].mainCategories); //its returning  undefined ?? wtf?!
  console.log(categories[0].hasOwnProperty("category")); //its returning false
  console.log(categories[0].hasOwnProperty("_id")); //its returning false
  console.log(categories[0].hasOwnProperty("mainCategories")); //its returning false
```

Object Result:

```
{
  category: [],
  _id: new ObjectId("6257233b897c3b8785ff625b"),
  mainCategories: [
    { id: 1000010100, name: 'Konut', subCategories: [Array] },
    { id: 1000010200, name: 'Devremülk', subCategories: [Array] },
    { id: 1000020100, name: 'İşyeri', subCategories: [Array] },
    { id: 1000020200, name: 'Arazi', subCategories: [Array] },
    {
      id: 1000020300,
      name: 'Turistik İşletme',
      subCategories: [Array]
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Something to try: `categories[0].hasOwnProperty('mainCategories')` to see if the object or a prototype is reported to have the property. Might be the console up to something strange.

Comment: What would you like to achieve? I mean, tried to target your documents within the array? .mainCategories[0]

Comment: Please put relevant code into the question as text, not in an image.  That is required here for a whole bunch of reasons.

Comment: @CertainPerformance im getting this result : `category hasOwnProperty: false
_id hasOwnProperty: false
mainCategories hasOwnProperty: false`

Comment: I suppose it's something about prototypes as well. It looks like a case of property shadowing, probably a property higher in the prototype chain is shadowing what you see in the first `console.log`. You can try `categories[0].__proto__.mainCategories` and `categories[0].__proto__.__proto__.mainCategories`

Comment: @VebDav I need `mainCategories` properties in frontend. But it comes as `undefined`.

Comment: I had similar issues: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72506449/how-to-find-value-in-array-of-object-in-mongodb/72506485#72506485) maybe this will help you.

Comment: @VebDav I think no, the screenshot is pretty eloquent

Comment: @firstlord  It's silly but maybe try like `categories[0]["mainCategories"];`.
Or try `const {mainCategories} = categories[0];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers given by Cristian Traìna and VebDav caused lightning in my brain. I couldn't find the exact solution to the problem on the internet. But different problems guided me. The problem stems from my stupidity. I forgot to enter the mainCategories field in the `mongoose category schema`. I added this and its fixed. Thank you so much everyone for your answers.

[image]

And now its returning mainCategories :)

[image]